# Taurus cannot load JDBC driver

Tags: jdbc, load-testing, taurus, jmeter-5.0

I have a .jmx file that uses SQL JDBC driver. When I run it using jmeter.bat, it runs without issues. However, running it with Taurus fails with message

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver
```

Anyone knows why so?

My JMeter is installed at C:/JMeter. The corresponding jar file is placed inside lib folder.

My Taurus is installed at C:/Taurus

Comment: What is the full exception stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

Probably Taurus run another JMeter instance:

> If there is no JMeter installed at the configured path Taurus will attempt to install the latest JMeter and associated plugins into this location (by default this is: ~/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/bin/jmeter). You can change this setting to your preferred JMeter location (consider putting it into the ~/.bzt-rc file).

So, could you check the JMeter path at `~/.bzt-rc` file?

It has following JMeter settings:

```
# JMeter settings

#modules:
#  jmeter:
#    properties:  # JMeter properties for every JMeter run
#      prop_name: prop value
#    system-properties:  # Java system properties
#      sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders: "true"
#    memory-xmx: 4G  # allow JMeter to use up to 4G of memory
#    path: ~/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/{version}/bin/jmeter  # path to local jmeter installation
#    version: 3.2  # version to use
#    plugins:  # plugins to install
#    - jpgc-json=2.2
#    - jmeter-ftp
#    - jpgc-casutg
```

So, add this string:

```
path: C:/Taurus  # path to local jmeter installation
```

Comment: Don't you need an `additional-classpath=mydriver.jar` section?  I'm not sure jmeter bzt plugin supports it. Never tried.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I installed JMeter first, then Taurus, so the file hierarchy is probably different from what others are used to (please see question).

When I look in the result folder (format YYYY-MM-DD_Time) and open jmeter-bzt.properties file, I see this line

> user.classpath=C:/Taurus/2019-01-31_13-51-47.334467;c:/jmeter/extras

So, I put the jar files in C:/jmeter/extras instead of the usual C:/jmeter/lib to make my jmx files work with Taurus.

Hope this helps someone.